# Perpetual Machines work or do they?

Tags: science-based

Perpetual machines are branded to be non- working useless machines. But somehow it seems that a human is itself a perpetual machine. What seems to be most absurd is that it is not yet concluded whether a perpetual machine could be used for various important purposes. Could anyone answer my question??

Comment: "A human is itself a perpetual machine" - Humans are not machines, in a biological sense, and they certainly aren't perpetual.

Comment: Go ask on Physics SE, they'll tell you no they don't exist.

Comment: "somehow it seems that a human is itself a perpetual machine" how, energy goes in, energy comes out, more energy doesn't come out than went in, conservation of energy is conserved, I think you need to look up the definition of a "perpetual motion machine" because you don't seem to understand the words.

Comment: Ignoring wear and tear maintenance of the 'gears',  humans only run as long as you continously add more fuel. By that definition, they are not perpetual, which are said to need no extra fuel added.

Comment: According to wikipedia, "A perpetual motion machine is a hypothetical machine that can do work indefinitely without an energy source". Humans are not machines, not eternal, and need energy

Comment: you can read up the laws of thermodynamic but anyway here's a simpler version: 1st law - you cannot win!(energy is conserved), 2nd law - you cannot break even!(energy to do work will decrease), 3rd law - you cannot quit!(to reach absolute zero is just impossible)

Answer (score 1):

No they dont exist, cannot work, and thus cannot be used for anything useful. If you would like to understand why you need to read up on the laws of thermodynamics.

Comment: The person who actually answers should maybe consider at least reciting or at the bare minimum linking the wikipedia page for those important laws. Ideally of course you should include an explanation of those laws and then conclude why they don't work. Otherwise this answer is useless

Comment: The person asked a yes or no question. The answer is no. Thermal dynamics are 6th grade level science, they arent obscure by any means. A basic google session is all it requires to educate one's self on the subject.

Comment: Please go outside and ask the next 10 (willing) people you meet what the first and 2nd law of thermodynamics are or why those machines don't work and see how many are correct. Maybe try the same with 6th grade physics teachers and then see how many of them really understood those laws.

Comment: Yeah, TCAT... this needed just a bit more.  The problem is the world is full of "perpetual motion machines" that aren't actually that.  It fools a great many non-science people (whether they've had 6th grade science or not).  It's easy to claim "no such thing" until you see the many energy-swapping fits-within-the-rules machines pleasantly and fraudulently labeled "perpetual motion" on YouTube and then blame the uninitiated for not being initiated and thereby knowing better.  Long story short, this was a bit ruthless, especially to a first-time poster.

Comment: Maybe consider critiques of questions in comments? Otherwise, you're just encouraging these questions

Comment: More importantly, don't answer off topic questions. It creates bad habits and sets bad precedence

Comment: Yall are right. Probably let myself get a bit miffed over the obvious nature of the question and got carried away. Im a former marine and I tend to be pretty laconic when im annoyed to the detriment of discourse.